# Subtraction of unlike doubles resulting in 0.0

Tags: java, android

I am trying to subtract two small doubles, both of which I have gotten by using the system time like so:

```
start = System.currentTimeMillis();
end = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

I then subtracted the two (`end - start`) and attempted to store the value into a `double[] data` array I made. For some reason the result of that, instead of being a double, keeps on outputting `0.0`.

I initialized the data array as follows:

```
private double[] data = new double[maxTaps+1];
```

where `MaxTaps` is some constant

I am using a textView to output onto the screen what the values are as I go. For some reason, when I just print out (`end - start`), it will give me a double that is non-zero. But if I put that double (`end - start`) into my data array and try to print the double from the data array, it results in 0.0.

For example: I am trying to get the time from when a button changes color to when it is tapped. After changing the color of the button I set the start time. Then when the user taps the specific button, the end time is recorded using the way above and the two are subtracted and added into my data array. The weird part is as follows: when I output the data like below, the result is always 0.0

```
bottomText.setText("Data point " + Integer.toString(taps) + ": " + String.valueOf(data[taps]));
```

but, if I change `data[taps]` to (`end - start`) (shown below), then I get a reasonable value

```
bottomText.setText("Data point " + Integer.toString(taps) + ": " + String.valueOf((end - start));
```

I am really lost here because they should be the same value.

Also, I am just including what one of my click listeners looks like for a button, that might also be useful

```
buttonTopLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view){
            if (lit == 1) {
                end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                data[taps] = (end - start);
                taps++;
                buttonTopLeft.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run(){
                        doUpdate();
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
         }
    });
```

Comment: so, you don't suppose the definition of `data[]` might be even the slightest bit pertinent to the question?

Comment: *instead of being a double, keeps on outputting 0.0* -- That is a double ;)

Comment: More context is needed. It might be that you're incrementing `taps` after setting the value, so then `data[taps]` should be 0

Comment: @MikeNakis this is how I defined data[] in this case. I am sorry for not including that in my question. private double[] data = new double[maxTaps+1];

Comment: @lucasvw I don't think I understand what you are saying. I am incrementing taps after setting the value. You can see this happening in the code I appended to my question. I want to get the (end-start) time at index 0 (first tap), then keep on increasing tap to keep updating data[]

Comment: @cricket_007 Haha yeah let me change my title, 0.0 obviously ins't the right double though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likelly because you are incrementing taps, after you are setting the value and the new `data[taps]` is actually zero. The data at `data[taps-1]` is the value you are after. Lets say taps is at 0, then you set the first element -`data[0]= 15.0` . Then `taps++` now taps is 1, and you will actually print `data[1]`  which is not set so it shows 0

Comment: Yup, after changing a few things based on your comment I just had to make sure that I wasn't calling it if taps was at 0 to avoid a null error. Thank you!